# Store auto-updating object inside React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this situation but I don't know if it's ok to do something like this.
If I save an object inside the state of my component, can the object modify itself without using setState?

File A.js

```
export default class A {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    setValue(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

File B_Component.js

```
import React from "react";
import A from "./A";

class B_Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            aObj = new A("foo")
        }
    }

    bar = () => {
        this.state.aObj.setValue("bar");
    }

    ...render etc...
}
```

Basically this should modify the state of the component without using setState.
Is this correct or there may be problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct or there may be problems?

There may be problems. :-) If you're rendering that object's `value`, then you're breaking one of the fundamental rules of React, which is that [you can't directly modify state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). If you do, the component won't re-render.

Instead, you create a new object and save the new object in state:

```
bar = () => {
    this.setState({aObj: new A("bar")});
}
```

Or if you want to reuse other aspects of the object and only change `value`:

```
bar = () => {
    const aObj = new A(this.state.aObj); // Where this constructor copies all the 
                                         // relevant properties
    aObj.setValue("bar");
    this.setState({aObj});
}
```

The `A` constructor would be

```
constructor(other) {
    this.value = other.value;
    // ...repeat for any other properties...
}
```

Or you might give `A` a new function, `withValue`, that creates a new `A` instance with an updated `value`:

```
class A {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        // ...other stuff...
    }

    withValue(value) {
        const a = new A(value);
        // ...copy any other stuff to `a`...
        return a;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
bar = () => {
    this.setState({aObj: this.state.aObj.withValue("bar")});
}
```